# Como Hago Que las Cards sean responsivas

Tags: css, css3, responsive, diseño

me podrían ayudar?
trato de entender css3 y quisiera saber como puedo hacer para arreglar la vista responsive.

aquí les dejo mi código.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
body h1{
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: -5%;
}
.contenedor{
 position: relative;
 width: 1000px;
 margin: 150px auto 0;
 height: auto;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
 grid-template-rows: 440px;
 grid-gap: 40px; 
}
.contenedor .card{
 position: relative;
 background: #000;
  overflow: hidden; 
 border-radius: 10px;
 transition: 0.5s;

}
.contenedor .card:hover{
 transform: translateY(-20px);
 box-shadow: 0 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.contenedor .card .img-box{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 transition: 0.5s;
}
.contenedor .card:hover .img-box{
 opacity: 0.5;
}
.contenedor .card .img-box img{
 width: 100%;
}
.contenedor .card .content{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 60%;
 bottom: -100%;
 padding: 20px;
 padding-top: 60px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 text-align: center; 
 transition: 0.5s;
}
.contenedor .card:hover .content{
 bottom: 0;
}
/*Aca estan los hermanos... Importante cambiar si solo se quiere 1*/
.contenedor .card:nth-child(1) .content{
 background: linear-gradient(0deg, #0075F2, transparent);
}
.contenedor .card:nth-child(2) .content{
 background: linear-gradient(0deg, #30F200, transparent);
}
.contenedor .card:nth-child(3) .content{
 background: linear-gradient(0deg, #EE00F2, transparent);
}
.contenedor .card .content h2{
 margin: 0 0 10px;
 padding: 0;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 20px; 
}
.contenedor .card .content h2 span{
 color: #ffeb3b;
 font-size: 15px;
}
.contenedor .card .content p{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 15px; 
}
.contenedor .card .content ul{
 display: flex;
 margin: 20px 0 0;
 padding: 0;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
.contenedor .card .content ul li{
 list-style: none;
}
.contenedor .card .content ul li a{
 color: #fff;
 padding: 0 10px;
 font-size: 18px;
 transition: 0.5s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 999px) {
 .contenedor{
  width: 100%;
 }
 .contenedor .card .img-box{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
 .contenedor .card .img-box img{
  width: 100%;
 }
 .contenedor .card .content{
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  bottom: -100%;
  padding: 0;
 }
}
```

```html
<body>
 <h1>Targeta de Presentación</h1>
 <div class="contenedor">
  <div class="card">
   <div class="img-box">
    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/E-commerce/Vertical/8.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="content">
    <h2>Carlos Zalazar <br><span>UX/UI Desinger</span></h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, voluptatibus officiis debitis delectus enim expedita.</p>
    
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
   <div class="img-box">
    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/E-commerce/Vertical/9.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="content">
    <h2>Carlos Zalazar <br><span>UX/UI Desinger</span></h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, voluptatibus officiis debitis delectus enim expedita.</p>
    
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
   <div class="img-box">
    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/E-commerce/Vertical/7.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="content">
    <h2>Carlos Zalazar <br><span>UX/UI Desinger</span></h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, voluptatibus officiis debitis delectus enim expedita.</p>
    
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Pues a simple vista es responsiva, ¿Cuál es el comportamiento que deseas, o cual es la falla que presenta?

Comment: @JheymanMejia ejecutaste el código que puse? al ejecutarlo me gustaría que la vista responsiva solo me permita ver una card como cuando usas bootstrap con la clase (col-12) y que no se vea esa franja negra abajo que nose como hacer para arreglarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Le dejo una solución que le puede ser de utilidad.

En tu diseño **CSS** realice algunas modificaciones para poder trabajar cómodamente con las etiquetas de `flexbox` y mejore el entorno de cada una de sus `Cards`.

Para el diseño **Responsive** Puede siempre usar condiciones `@media` y asignar las medidas de tamaño de pantalla que consideres. Para su caso no las use y utilice la etiqueta `flex:wrap` que permite acomodar los elementos según el tamaño del `viewport`, si un elemento no se acomoda lo envia a la parte de abajo para no dañar el diseño.

Espero le sirva.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans");
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.contenedor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 95%;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #FFF !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.contenedor .card {
  position: relative;
  background: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}

.contenedor .card:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-20px);
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.contenedor .card .img-box {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.contenedor .card:hover .img-box {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.contenedor .card .img-box img {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.contenedor .card .content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  bottom: -100%;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.contenedor .card:hover .content {
  bottom: 0;
}

/*Aca estan los hermanos... Importante cambiar si solo se quiere 1*/

.contenedor .card:nth-child(1) .content {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(#0075F2), to(transparent));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #0075F2, transparent);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #0075F2, transparent);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #0075F2, transparent);
}

.contenedor .card:nth-child(2) .content {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(#30F200), to(transparent));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #30F200, transparent);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #30F200, transparent);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #30F200, transparent);
}

.contenedor .card:nth-child(3) .content {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(#EE00F2), to(transparent));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #EE00F2, transparent);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #EE00F2, transparent);
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #EE00F2, transparent);
}

.contenedor .card .content h2 {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.contenedor .card .content h2 span {
  color: #ffeb3b;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.contenedor .card .content p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.contenedor .card .content ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.contenedor .card .content ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.contenedor .card .content ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title>Tarjeta Responsive</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="img-box">
                <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/E-commerce/Vertical/8.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <h2>Carlos Zalazar <br><span>UX/UI Desinger</span></h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, voluptatibus officiis debitis
                    delectus enim expedita.</p>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="img-box">
                <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/E-commerce/Vertical/9.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <h2>Carlos Zalazar <br><span>UX/UI Desinger</span></h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, voluptatibus officiis debitis
                    delectus enim expedita.</p>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="img-box">
                <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/E-commerce/Vertical/7.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <h2>Carlos Zalazar <br><span>UX/UI Desinger</span></h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, voluptatibus officiis debitis
                    delectus enim expedita.</p>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias, me ayudaste muchísimo con esto.